# Angular theres a cleaner way of changing the DOM?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

my question is about if the way im doing this in my code is right or theres a better solution for this.

Here my Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let dataHolder of data; let i = index" ">


        <ul>
            <li class='list-item' [id]=datas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate('+numberArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,-'+Height+'px) rotate(-'+numberArray[i]+'deg)' }"
             (click)="alertMethod(data, i)">

                <div class='list-link' [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate('+numberArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,+'+Height+'px) rotate('+0+'deg)' }">
                    <img alt='notfound' [src]=imageDirection[i]>
                </div>
                <div class='test'>
                    <img alt='notfound' class='img' src='any Icon'>
                </div>
                <div class='test'>
                    {{ dataHolder.name }}
                </div>


            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Every data it holds is from 1 Component.

First I got data with strings in it, these data i loop trough and show them off at the screen. Afterwards its getting rotated around the screen, so its getting a new position. 
The Code is doing well and every step i mentioned finish before the user can see the app. But now as a newbie on Angular i want to ask you guys if theres a better/cleaner way to change code in the DOM (new Styles, adding new Elements, creating new paragraphs, etc.) like in my code example. If you need more examples i can give more.

I would really appreciate your help, because at the moment im unsure if the way im model my DOM is not clean and im going into the wrong way.

Comment: Looks very reasonable to me but I would prefer to extract those transforms into constants that I could reference, reuse, and keep out of the already convoluted angular Dom syntax, which built on the convoluted existing Dom syntax... also, the alt is oft-repeated and could be factored into a directive.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your reply! Do you mean sth like `[ngStyle]='getTransform()'`? With a method i could reuse it and i wouldnt need to call the "numberArray" from the DOM.

Comment: Basically, although I would prefer a property to a method aesthetically. You might also create a simple es module that exports these as free-standing functions or constants. Then you could assign them as members of your viewmodel to bring them into scope while facilitating reuse. You can also inject them as dependencies.

Comment: Also note that angular has an animation DSL that you can apply in the component decoratorfactory to describe animations but I find it confusing personally.

Comment: Well i got already stucked at the first step. I wanted to get it working with a property, but i dont know how to get the different numbers from numberArray with a property into the transform values. Thats why i tryed it with a method, so i can loop trough the array with an index i, but sth is wrong with my string. Maybe you can tell me pls whats wrong there? `getTransforming(i):string{
    return 'transform: rotate('+this.numberArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,-'+this.Height+'px) rotate(-'+this.numberArray[i]+'deg)'; 
  }` and `[ngStyle]="getTransforming(i)"`. Ng Style doesnt accept the string.

Comment: You should use a method if you want parameterization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have looks very reasonable to me but I would prefer to extract those transforms into constants or functions that I could reference, reuse, and keep out of the already convoluted Angular DOM syntax, which is based on the already convoluted existing DOM syntax.

The alt is oft-repeated and could be factored into a directive.

I might go about it like this

**list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let dataHolder of data; let i = index">
    <ul>
        <li class='list-item'
          [id]=datas.id
          [ngStyle.transform]="createTransform(numberArray[i], height, numberArray[i])"
          (click)="alertMethod(data, i)">

            <div class='list-link'
              [ngStyle.transform]="createTransform(numberArray[i], height, 0)">
              <img alt='notfound' [src]=imageDirection[i]>
            </div>
            <div class='test'>
              <img alt='notfound' class='img' src='any Icon'>
            </div>
            <div class='test'>
                {{ dataHolder.name }}
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component,  ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';

import template from './list.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export default class {
  numberArray: number[] = [];

  createTransform = createTransform;
}

// testability for the win!
export function createTransform(primaryAngle: number, height: number, secondaryAngle = 0) {
  return `rotate(${primaryAngle}deg) translate(0, -${height}px) rotate(-${secondaryAngle}deg)`;
}
```

However, be sure to look into the Angular official animation library.

Comment: Glad I could be of service.